# Webpack plugin to automatically upload changed files via FTP

Tags: npm, webpack, file-upload, ftp

I'm building a Wordpress theme and have recently switched from using [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) to Webpack/Babel/PostCSS etc... to do all of the SASS and Javascript compiling manually so that I can add more custom functionality.

The last functionality of Prepros that I need to recreate is the automatic file uploading via FTP when a file is edited. I've been searching around for a while now and can't really find any Webpack plugins that will automatically upload files to a server via FTP whilst also giving me lots of options (i.e. specifying file extensions to upload/ignore).

**What's the best way to automatically upload files to a server via FTP once they have been changed (saved) using Webpack?**

At the moment it looks like my best option is [webpack-ftp-upload-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-ftp-upload-plugin), but it doesn't look like there are many customisation options as I mentioned above...

Comment: I guess this is not a good way to copy to the server using the webpack. What if the generated code will be bad, sometimes it happens that the dev version is ok and in the prod version something does not work and what will you overwrite data on the server?

A better solution would be to use the command line eg. Such a library [ftp-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-deploy) In package.js in the script section, set `commit` to commit.js and put everything in it nicely.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I understand what you mean but I don't care about the uploaded code being "bad" and overriding the server. I'll be using this to automatically upload to a "live" dev server (i.e. not the final production server - just a way for the client to see the progress) and so something "bad" being uploaded does not matter as I can fix it straight away

Answer (score 1):

Use this script after completing build [ftp-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-deploy). Right after the compilation, the bulldog will be deploy. You do not need to have a plugin in the webpack

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "concurrently \"yarn prod"\  \"yarn deploy\"",
 "prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production",
 "deploy": "node deploy"
}
```

Comment: Will this automatically upload a single file when I make a change to it and save it?

Comment: Rather, it is not possible to send only these changed files. But from what I know is a webpack, if a file changes, it generates new bundles, all new files? It may be better to exclude files that you do not want to send to the server.